# efficiently generating all integers within a binary mask

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I have some binary mask `mask`. (e.g. 0b101011011101)

Is there an efficient method of computing all integers `k` such that `k & mask == k`? (where `&` is the bitwise AND operator) (alternatively, k & ~mask == 0)

If `mask` has `m` ones, then there are exactly 2<sup>m</sup> numbers that satisfy this property, so it seems like there should be some kind of process that is O(2<sup>m</sup>). Enumerating the integers less than the mask is wasteful (though easy to eliminate values that do not apply).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... you can identify all the single bit patterns like as follows, since the least significant 1 bit of any integer `k` is cleared when calculating `k & (k-1)`:

```
def onebits(x):
    while x > 0:
        # find least significant 1 bit
        xprev = x
        x &= x-1
        yield x ^ xprev
```

and then I can use the [ruler function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RulerFunction.html) to XOR in various combinations of 1 bits to emulate which bits of a counter are toggled each time:

```
def maskcount(mask):
    maskbits = []
    m = 0
    for ls1 in onebits(mask):
        m ^= ls1
        maskbits.append(m)
    # ruler function modified from 
    # http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaCoroutinesVersusPythonGenerators
    def ruler(k):
        for i in range(k):
            yield i
            for x in ruler(i): yield x    
    x = 0
    yield x
    for k in ruler(len(maskbits)):
        x ^= maskbits[k]
        yield x
```

which looks like this:

```
>>> for x in maskcount(0xc05):
...     print format(x, '#016b')
0b00000000000000
0b00000000000001
0b00000000000100
0b00000000000101
0b00010000000000
0b00010000000001
0b00010000000100
0b00010000000101
0b00100000000000
0b00100000000001
0b00100000000100
0b00100000000101
0b00110000000000
0b00110000000001
0b00110000000100
0b00110000000101
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to solve the problem is to find the bits that are set in mask, and then simply count with i, but then replacing the bits of i with corresponding bits from the mask.

```
def codes(mask):
    bits = filter(None, (mask & (1 << i) for i in xrange(mask.bit_length())))
    for i in xrange(1 << len(bits)):
        yield sum(b for j, b in enumerate(bits) if (i >> j) & 1)

print list(codes(39))
```

That gives you O(log(N)) work per iteration (where N is the number of bits set in `mask`).

It's possible to be more efficient, and do O(1) work per iteration by counting using [gray codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code). With gray code counting, only a single bit changes each iteration so it's possible to efficiently update the current value, `v`. Obviously this is much harder to understand than the simple solution above.

```
def codes(mask):
    bits = filter(None, (mask & (1 << i) for i in xrange(mask.bit_length())))
    blt = dict((1 << i, b) for i, b in enumerate(bits))
    p, v = 0, 0
    for i in xrange(1 << len(bits)):
        n = i ^ (i >> 1)
        v ^= blt.get(p^n, 0)
        p = n
        yield v

print list(codes(39))
```

A disadvantage of using gray codes is that the results are not returned in numeric order. But luckily that wasn't a condition in the question!

Comment: If you change your `blt` lookup to have values that are accumulated least significant bits (e.g. `1`, `1001`, `11001`, `1011001` rather than `1`, `1000`, `10000`, `1000000`), then you can change the count from Gray codes to regular counting. If you do that, your solution is equivalent to mine. (bitlength(i ^ (i>>1)) is the ruler function)